# Django - problem with writing to database

Tags: python, django, database, django-forms, admin

I have a problem, the urls form works but I can't see the records in url/admin, can I ask for help, thank you :D

SOF wants me to add more details otherwise it doesn't transfer, I don't know what more I can add, generally temapals and urls work.

---

```
class Note(models.Model):
    """..."""
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Note"
        verbose_name_plural = "Notes"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.notes
```

---

```
class NoteView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            textN = Note.objects.all().order_by('notes')
            form = NoteAddForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('Files/menu')
        else:
            textN = NoteAddForm()
        return render(request, 'Files/note.html', {'textN': textN})
```

---

```
class NoteAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """New note add form"""

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = '__all__'
```

---

```
{% extends 'Files/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Notatnik{% endblock %}
<h2>Notatnik Dietetyka/ Zalecenia ręczne </h2>

{% block content %}

    <form action="/send/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ textN }}
        <label>
            <input type="text" class="btn btn-second btn-lg">
            <button><a href="{% url 'send' %}">Wyślij formularz</a></button>
        </label>


    </form>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><a href="{% url 'menu' %}">Powrót</a></button>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: is ```form.save()``` being called? what i mean to say is is your form submission valid?

Comment: @KaviHarjani the real issue is that he is checking for a `post request` inside of the class `get` method. The `get()` is really equivalent to `if request.method == 'GET'`. So there's no way the method will have a `request.method == 'POST'` being `True`. Hence, it's always `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Within your `NoteView` class in `views.py` file is where the issue is.

I see you have an `if statement` checking for `if request.method == 'POST'` within the `class-based view` `get()`. The `get()` is equivalent to `if request.method == 'GET'`. Therefore, what you might want to do is to override the `post()` on the class instead. For example:

```
class NoteView(View):
     template_name = 'Files/note.html'

     # Use the get method to pass the form to the template
     def get(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
          textN = NoteAddForm()

          return render(request, self.template_name, {'textN': textN})

     # Use the post method to handle the form submission
     def post(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
          # textN = Note.objects.all().order_by('notes') -> Not sure why you have this here...
          form = NoteAddForm(request.POST)

          if form.is_valid():
               form.save()

               # if the path is... i.e: path('success/', SucessView.as_view(), name='success')
               return redirect('success')  # Redirect upon submission 
          else:
               print(form.errors)  # To see the field(s) preventing the form from being submitted

          # Passing back the form to the template in the name 'textN'
          return render(request, self.template_name, {'textN': form})
```

Ideally, that should fix the issue you're having.

**Updates**

On the form, what I'd suggest having is...

```
# Assuming that this view handles both the get and post request
<form method="POST">  # Therefore, removing the action attribute from the form
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ textN }}

    # You need to set the type as "submit", this will create a submit button to submit the form
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-second btn-lg" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, Further I don't have the data in django/admin. I wonder if the submit button is well done?                                           <input type="text" class="btn btn-second btn-lg">
            <button><a href="{% url 'send' %}">Wyślij formularz</a></button>

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can view the updated section of the answer.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then you can re-edit your post and add your `urls.py` file that has the url `send` path in it. Would like to see that to see what path goes to the `NoteView` class.

Comment: path('note/', NoteView.as_view(), name='note'),

Comment: ACTION, big THX. Just doesn't refer me to the main page yet.

I'm posting the URLs because maybe someone will find the whole thing useful

Comment: I have another problem in this place return redirect('menu.html') because it should be Files/note.html and it is http://127.0.0.1:8010/note/note.html that i think ;),  TemplateDoesNotExist at /note/

Comment: Works THX :) return redirect('/')

Comment: Good! If the answer solved your initial problem, to help others you should probably accept it as the answer to your question. :-)

Comment: Task solved - thank you Damoiskii

Comment: Good... Np! :-D